Tensorflow Lite Dynamic Output shape
i have a tensorflow object detection model. when i load it with
tf.saved_model.load()

i see this signatures:
{'detection_scores': TensorShape([1, 100]), 'detection_boxes': TensorShape([1, 100, 4]), 'detection_classes': TensorShape([1, 100]), 'detection_anchor_indices': TensorShape([1, 100]), 'raw_detection_scores': TensorShape([1, 51150, 91]), 'raw_detection_boxes': TensorShape([1, 51150, 4]), 'detection_multiclass_scores': TensorShape([1, 100, 91]), 'num_detections': TensorShape([1])}

after i converted it with
tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model()
 

and try to use it with
tf.lite.Interpreter()

i see this signatures
[{'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:6',
  'index': 474,
  'shape': array([    1, 51150,     4], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([    1, 51150,     4], dtype=int32),
  'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
   'quantized_dimension': 0},
  'sparsity_parameters': {}},
 {'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:0',
  'index': 2234,
  'shape': array([1, 1], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([ 1, -1], dtype=int32),
  'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
   'quantized_dimension': 0},
  'sparsity_parameters': {}},
 {'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:5',
  'index': 2199,
  'shape': array([1], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([1], dtype=int32),
  'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
   'quantized_dimension': 0},
  'sparsity_parameters': {}},
 {'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:7',
  'index': 494,
  'shape': array([    1, 51150,    91], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([    1, 51150,    91], dtype=int32),
  'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
   'quantized_dimension': 0},
  'sparsity_parameters': {}},
 {'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:1',
  'index': 2287,
  'shape': array([1, 1, 1], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([ 1, -1, -1], dtype=int32),
  'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
   'quantized_dimension': 0},
  'sparsity_parameters': {}},
 {'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:2',
  'index': 2269,
  'shape': array([1, 1], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([ 1, -1], dtype=int32),
  'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
   'quantized_dimension': 0},
  'sparsity_parameters': {}},
 {'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:4',
  'index': 2216,
  'shape': array([1, 1], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([ 1, -1], dtype=int32),
  'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
   'quantized_dimension': 0},
  'sparsity_parameters': {}},
 {'name': 'StatefulPartitionedCall:3',
  'index': 2252,
  'shape': array([1, 1, 1], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([ 1, -1, -1], dtype=int32),
  'dtype': numpy.float32,
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
   'quantized_dimension': 0},
  'sparsity_parameters': {}}]

from
interpreter.get_output_details()

how can i convert dynamic shapes to static ones? and why
tf.lite

convert static shape like (1, 100, 4) to (1, -1, -1)? i try different methods but none of them worked.
